# Move related products to Right Column on product page Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.8, product, product-list, products-management

In Magento 1.9.0.1, on product page "Related Products" appear just under the products description. I want to move this block to Right Column.

Please advise how to do this?

Comment: If your problem was solved, please select one of the answers as "accepted" to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1. At app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml. Move following code:

to

```
    <reference name="right">

    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>,
```

and make it looks like below:

```
    <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

1. At the page app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml, remove following:

   ```
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>
   ```

Comment: it works for me , My code as like         <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="treemenu" template="catalog/product/list/related_owl.phtml"/>
        </reference>

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you're mixing up related products and up-sells. Up-sells are usually underneath product descriptions, related products are usually on sidebars and cross-sells can be found from checkouts.